# How to attach images using pymupdf

Tags: python, pypdf, pdfminer, pymupdf

I have a pdf where 2 pages have total of 6 attachment boxes where you can click on them and after clicking you can choose the image file and it will be inserted in the pdf, so I want to do this using python I have tried pymupdf and after checking it is showing me it is one of the widgets as button but I don't know exactly how can I use pymupdf to upload the images automatically, I have tried several techniques but it didn't help so I had to remove the attachment boxes. Can anyone please help me out here? I have used this also as I saw in the documentation adding an annot_file or embedded file can do the trick but I am not sure and confused, has anyone ever did it?

[image]

After clicking on one of the image icon

[image]

I have tried several techniques there were a few methods of attaching files using annotations and update_file for the document object. If this helps to understand the problem more clearly. Thanks

Comment: @KJ thanks for your comment, I do not know how to share the pdf files here on StackOverflow but I can attach screenshots if it helps

Comment: @KJ I want to use this python library pymupdf or some other library that can help.